# I installed multiple libraries the same way and React is registering all but one of them. Why can't it find this particular module?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I did "npm install --save -g pondjs" but when I ran my code, I got this error message:

```
./src/Components/Tseries.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'pondjs' in '/Users/<ME>/Google Drive/code/React/projectmanager/src/Components'
```

Here is the header in my js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TimeSeries, TimeRange, TimeRangeEvent } from 'pondjs';
import { Charts, ChartContainer, ChartRow, YAxis, LineChart, Resizable, EventChart } from 'react-timeseries-charts';
import myJson from '../data/info.json';
```

The SO questions on this topic related to user-created components, not files installed via "npm install". I'm not sure if I installed it in the wrong place, or if React is looking in the wrong place. But pondjs should be available to React. The other libraries I've downloaded are. Why is this library different?

Comment: Could you try and not install it globally, but locally instead? `npm intall --save pondjs`

Comment: How are you executing your application? Are you using babel to compile your code? What command is generating the not found error?

Comment: @Tholle Installing it locally fixed it! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `-g` flag when installing. The `-g` flag allows you to access the installed npm package via command line, but is not a part of your local project files.

If you need it both locally and globally, npm install it twice (once with the -g flag and once without).

Comment: additionally, if you need global access to command, [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) might be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript, I don't think there's a type file for that package, so the compiler may give a warning even if the package is available.